# "SQL command not properly ended" error message when querying for table names in my Node application

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, node-oracledb, database-link

I'm getting the following error when executing the following query with node-oracledb:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS || '@' || :db
WHERE OWNER = :schema
    AND (
        OBJECT_TYPE = ''TABLE''
        OR OBJECT_TYPE = ''VIEW''
        OR OBJECT_TYPE = ''SYNONYM''
    )
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME
```

If I execute this query in an Oracle console (substituting the placeholders for actual values, of course), it executes fine. However, when I execute this in my Node application, I get the following error:

```
"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"
```

Is anyone able to assist with why I'm getting this error? I can confirm that my placeholders are definitely populating with the values I intended them to be populated with.

Thanks!

edit:

Even if I try do:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS || @ || :db
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS || '@' || :db
WHERE OWNER = :schema
    AND (
        OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
        OR OBJECT TYPE = 'VIEW'
        OR OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM'
    )
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME
```

- Firstly, there is a typo error in your query. You have a missing **underscore** in OBJECT TYPE `OR OBJECT TYPE = 'VIEW'`.
- You cannot execute a SQL with **dynamic object names**. SQL must have static object names. **DATABASE LINK** is a database object, you must provide the static name at run time. You can only provide **placeholders** as **bind variables for literals**.

If you want to make it dynamic, then you need to (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** in **PL/SQL**. You need to prepare the string dynamically and then execute it.

For example, In **SQL*Plus**:

```
var db varchar2(30);
var schema varchar2(30);
exec :db := 'database_name'
exec :schema := 'OWNER'

SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  v_sql         VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_object_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  v_sql:= 'SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS@'||:db||' WHERE OWNER = :schema     
AND (        
OBJECT_TYPE = ''TABLE''
OR OBJECT_TYPE = ''VIEW''        
OR OBJECT_TYPE = ''SYNONYM''
)
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql into v_object_name using :db, :schema;
END;
/
```

Or, you can have **DATABASE LINK** as a static name:

First I create the database link:

```
SQL> CREATE DATABASE LINK TEST
  2    CONNECT TO SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY tiger USING 'pdborcl';

Database link created.
```

Added the following entry in **tnsnames.ora** file:

```
test =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ocalhost)(PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER=DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME=pdborcl.in.oracle.com)
    )
  )
```

Let's execute in **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> var schema varchar2(30);
SQL> exec :schema := 'SCOTT'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME
  2  FROM ALL_OBJECTS@test
  3  WHERE OWNER = :schema
  4      AND (
  5          OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
  6          OR OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
  7          OR OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM'
  8      )
  9  ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME
 10  /

OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------
BONUS
DEPT
EMP
EMP_VIEW
SALGRADE
```

Comment: Hey Lalit - you definitely can have placeholders for names. I'm writing a NodeJS application and I am using a prepared statement. The typo was a result of me not copy-pasting my code - I just wrote it from the screen for some reason.

Comment: I might just quickly note that I'm trying to execute this from a NodeJS application using the node-oracledb driver.

Comment: @DaveCooper Updated the answer  with a complete working test case. You cannot use placeholders as bind variables for database objects in SQL. You can use them only for literals.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it hasn't actually answered my question. This would be misleading to others trying to solve the same problem as me.

Comment: @DaveCooper You mean you want to do it in pure SQL by passing database link name dynamically? That's not possible, you will have to prepare the sql as a string and then make sure the string has all the values correctly formed at run time. Could you post your prepared statement?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this one out. Turns out it was just my misunderstanding of how variable binding works. I thought I could bind to anything I wanted to in my query. Turns out you can't :P

I modified my query to look like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS@<HARDCODED DB NAME HERE>
WHERE OWNER = :schema
AND (
    OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
    OR OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
    OR OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM'
)
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME;
```

And it all worked perfectly!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but isn't that exactly what was suggested in the answer? Your query and the very last query in the answer looks the same.

Comment: Sort of - but it's definitely not directly addressing the question. There is no need for the (ab)use of "execute immediate" or anything like that. I personally think the answer, whilst informative, is a bit too convoluted. If his answer is clarified/tidied up, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.